# What is the best way of writing a collection schema to map another collection?

Tags: mongodb

In mongodb I have many collection like below

```
boys_fashion
girls_fashion
gents_fashion
ladies_fashion
girls_accessories
gents_accessories
ladies_accessories
```

based on some fields I need to use different collection. So for that I thought to create a collection which will map to a specific collection. Below is the collection I have created for that.

```
{
    "type" : "Fashion",
    "gender" : "Gents",
    "kids" : "true",
    "collection" : "boys_fashion"
}
{
    "type" : "Accessories",
    "gender" : "Ladies",
    "kids" : "false",
    "collection" : "ladies_accessories"
}
{
    "type" : "Fashion",
    "gender" : "Gents",
    "kids" : "false",
    "collection" : "gents_fashion"
}
{
    "type" : "Accessories",
    "gender" : "Ladies",
    "kids" : "true",
    "collection" : "girls_accessories"
}
 {
    "type" : "Accessories",
    "gender" : "Gents",
    "kids" : "true",
    "collection" : "gents_accessories"
}
{
    "type" : "Accessories",
    "gender" : "Gents",
    "kids" : "false",
    "collection" : "gents_accessories"
}
```

Is this is the right way to do this? or please suggest me some other ways

If I stored like below(the above option is similar to RDBMS. Since its mongo I guess I used this way). How can I write a query for fetching the collection?

```
{
    "fashion" : {
        "gents" : {
            "true" : "boys_fashion",
            "false" : "gents_fashion"
        }
    },
    "accessories" : {
        "ladies" : {
            "true" : "girls_accessories",
            "false" : "ladies_accessories"
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what "fashion", "accessories" but playing devils advocate here, why not put the gender, kids properties on each other documents and combined in to 2 collections?

Comment: For kids the collection will differ

Comment: Hence its a huge records I am splitting it into different collections

Comment: I  couldn't understand your question correctly. But anyway, designing collections is largely based on your read and write scenarios. So can you add the business use cases where you will be writing data and the use cases  where you will be reading data. It need to be optimized for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the collection like below.

```
 /* 1 */
    {
        "type" : "fashion",
        "category" : [ 
            {
                "value" : "gents",
                "true" : "boys_fashion",
                "false" : "gents_fasion"
            }
            
        ]
    }
    
    /* 2 */
    {
        "type" : "accessories",
        "category" : [ 
            {
                "value" : "ladies",
                "true" : "girls_accessories",
                "false" : "ladies_accessories"
            } 
           
        ]
    }
```

and will fetch the data using the below query

```
findOne({"type":type,"category.value":cvalue},{"_id": 0, "category": {"$elemMatch": {"value": cvalue}}})
```

Answer (score 1):

- Assumptions:

  - There were one collection before and you split them into multiple collections as they are getting large and you want to solve it without sharing.
- I would not even create a collection for the following data. This data is static reference data and will act as a router. On start up, application loads this data and creates a router.

```
    {
      "type" : "Fashion",
      "gender" : "Gents",
      "kids" : "true",
      "collection" : "boys_fashion"
    }
    {
      "type" : "Accessories",
      "gender" : "Ladies",
      "kids" : "false",
      "collection" : "ladies_accessories"
    }
    ...
```

- What do I mean by creating a kind of router by that static configuration file? Lets say you receive a query fashionable items for baby girls. This router will tell you, `hey you need to search girls_accessories collection`. And you send the query to `girls_accessories` collection and return the result.
- Lets take another example, you receive a query for fashionable items for female. This router will tell you `hey you need to search, ladies_accessories and girls_accessories`. You send the query to both collections and combine the result and send it back.

**Conclusion**

If my assumptions are correct, you don't need a collection to store the reference data. What you have done is manual sharding by splitting the data across different collections, the reference data will act as  router to tell you where to search and combine

**Update based on comments**

- Query does not involve multiple collections
- Administrator can add new collection and application should query it without modifying code.

**Solution 1**

- You create a collection for the reference data too
- Downside to this is that every query involves two calls to database. First to fetch the static data and second to the `data` collection

**Solution 2**

- You create a collection for the reference data too
- You also build a Dao on top of that which uses `@Cacheable` for the method that return this data.
- You also add a method in Dao to clear the cache with `@CacheEvict` and have a rest endpoint like `/refresh-static-data` that will call this method`
- Downside to this method is that whenever administrator add new collection, you need to call the endpoint.

**Solution 3**

- Same as solution 2 but instead of having an endpoint to clear the cache, you combine it with scheduler

```
    @Scheduled(fixedRate = ONE_DAY)
    @CacheEvict(value = { CACHE_NAME })
    public void clearCache() {      
    }
```

- Downside to this solution is that you have to come up with a period for `fixedRate` which is acceptable to your business

Comment: The last one i don't have such case. I don't need to fetch from different collection and no need to combine both result. This is just a reference. So if the admin user created a new collection. Developer no need to change it in code

Comment: But you still need the Dao for that collection which administrator added and when you add the dao, you update the static config too. Are you doing that part dynamically? If so, I can update the answer bit differently

Comment: what is dao? The collection is creating from outside not from the code

Comment: Yes. That I understand. But what application uses the collection to query?. What language, it is written, how it will query?

Comment: I am using node and mongoose for db

Comment: I see. I should have clarified that first and I added the solutions as if the queries are executed by a spring boot app. If you don't have caching mechanism, then you will have to  go with solution 1 where every request involves two queries where first one tells which collection and then second gives data

Comment: I got the answer. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

Try to make subdocuments in MongoDB, instead of nested objects
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html